# Formula returning a #VALUE error for one cell but not another

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-365, error-correction

I am using Microsoft Excel 365 in which I am using a formula to cleanup the raw data that I got by copying and pasting the list information from [MTG Salvation card search](https://www.mtgsalvation.com/cards). Several observations about the raw data are:

1. I select and highlight via dragging from the name of the top item and then Shift+Left Click to the right of price of the last item  in the displayed list;
2. it comes with text wrap upon pasting (even if I keep the destination formatting from some pre-setup);
3. some of the raw pricing data comes with a deviation adjustment either following a "+" symbol or contained in parentheses.

I am trying to keep the essential price data and remove the deviation adjustments and convert the resulting data to a number value so I can do further numerical processing with it. The formula I am using is intended to take the raw price data that is in column G and output a numerical value of the cleaned up result in column H as follows:

```
=NUMBERVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT($G2,LEN($G2)-IFERROR(FIND("+",$G2),IFERROR(FIND("(",$G2),0))),"$",""))
```

The formula was assembled as shown because of the following reasons:

1. The FIND/SEARCH functions return an error if the string, "+" or "(" in my case, to be found is not. Hence, in no particular order, I first try to see if a "+" is present, if not then try to find a "(", and if neither is found then I trust the data to assume the raw data is a standard price.
2. Because I want just the actual price, I want everything prior to the "+" or "(", so I extract the portion of the data string using the LEFT function by subtracting from the length of the string the position of either the "+" or "(" or else 0 if neither is found.
3. To minimize any misinterpretation, I also remove all "$" symbols.

Additional things tried include:

1. Using TRIM to remove hanging white spaces in the data after doing the above but the outcome was the same as the simpler formula shown above. This is not surprising as the NUMBERVALUE function by itself ignores white spaces.
2. Switching the order of finding the "(" before looking for the "+", but this also did not change the outcome in Column H.
3. I even tested individual pieces of my formula to test the outcomes at each stage. The issue appears to be when evaluating the NUMBERVALUE function.

Here is a snip of my Excel worksheet:

[Snip of Excel worksheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBNCh.png)

Given what I am doing and having seen the surface level discrepancy about the #VALUE error outcomes, here is additional information about the error that Excel tells me and that I was able to discern.

1. When I hover over the error box, it tells me that "A value used in the formula is of the wrong data type".
2. The raw price data that had deviation adjustments within parentheses are the ones that are resulting in this error.
3. If you look at Cell K64 you will see that it displays the desired out come even though its corresponding column H value does not. It should be noted that the formula in K64 uses the length of cell K60, which left me a bit puzzled.
4. ***I found a solution***: Per what I shared in the above item, I explored playing with the length of the output of the FIND function when looking for "(" and add 1 to that starting location which shortens the number of characters I extract from the left by one. In other words, I explicitly avoid grabbing the preceding empty space prior to the opening parenthesis, which may not actually even be a proper empty space is some special embedded character from the webpage.
5. ***Partial Epiphany***: I realized that one of the issues I "miscalculated" was the number of characters I was extracting using LEFT. The parentheses makes the price string one character longer which in turns makes my LEN()-FIND() operation pull in the extra "space" for the entries with the deviation adjustment contained in parentheses. Of course, that still doesn't explain why that would cause a problem unless somehow that space was embedded in a strange way.

If anybody can tell me how I can do an easy, quick reliable inspection of the data be it after pasting into Excel or from the webpage itself so I can determine whether there is an obscure special character present, I'd be appreciative. I know that there is a simple VBE code I can type up, but I am looking for a more immediate, simpler approach.

Thank You!

Comment: This formula do the same work as per your forrnula : =0+MID(G2,2,FIND(" ",G2&" ")-2)

Comment: Thank you. I see. So the leading zero forces the outcome to be numeric? And the ampersand is a concatenation operator... interesting. Again, thank you!

Comment: I gave it a try and I get the #VALUE error as with my original attempt. It definitely is a shorter formula for string data that that looks like what I was working with but strongly suggests that there is some special non-printable character that was carried over from the copy of the website data. Thank you still for showing me the simpler formula.